# Compiling 1 library with 2 sub-libraries with Android Studio's CMake and NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, android-ndk

Working on an Android NDK project. The project is using CMake to build the C++ libraries.

The library has the following structue -

- Main Library

  - main.cpp
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - hello (sub library)/

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - include/

      - hello.h
    - src/

      - hello.c
  - world (sub library)/

    - CMakeLists.txt
    - include/

      - world.h
    - src/

      - world.c

The contents are the following:

main.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <hello.h>
#include <world.h>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_test_myapplication_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string str = hello() + world();
    return env->NewStringUTF(str.c_str());
}
```

CMakeLists.txt for main.cpp

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

 add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/hello)
 include_directories(src/main/cpp/hello)
 add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/world)
 include_directories(src/main/cpp/world)


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                        hello
                        world)
```

world.h

```
#include <string>

std::string world();
```

world.c

```
#include "world.h"

std::string world() {
    return std::string("world");
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (world)

add_definitions(/DVERSION="0.4.0")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Os")

include_directories(include/)

set(SOURCES
    src/world.c
    include/world.h
)


add_library(world STATIC IMPORTED
    ${SOURCES}
    )
target_include_directories(world PUBLIC ./)
```

The content is the same for the "hello" library as the only difference is the output returned from hello's function.

Now, my experience with CMake is close to non-existent and I can't get this to work. I'm constantly getting errors upon building it. Latest error is the following -

> CMake Error at src/main/cpp/hello/CMakeLists.txt:19
>   (target_include_directories):   Cannot specify include directories for
>   imported target "hello". CMake Error at
>   src/main/cpp/world/CMakeLists.txt:19 (target_include_directories):
>   Cannot specify include directories for imported target "world".

I just can't find a way to compile all of it into a simple library that will be used in the app. Sometimes I get " not found", sometimes it can't find the header files and etc.

I'd appericiate if someone will be able to post a simple structure and CMake of the correct way of doing so as I'm lost.

In the actual project I try to use libmicrohttpd, but again, can't make it work. I've tried using CentOS's libraries but Android Studio seems to use the system's libraries which causes things to get messed up. This is the reason for which I download the library and try to compile it via Android Studio.

So, again, if anyone will be able to find a way to compile all of the 3 libraries together into a single library (main) which connected the other 2 (hello, world), I'd greatly appericiate it.

Much appericiated.

Comment: Why do you need *IMPORTED* option? It implies that a library is **already built** outside of CMake, which seems is not your case (you add sources to the library). Simply remove this option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I removed IMPORTED, and now when I build it  I get the following error - 

`Android Projects\MyApplication\app\src\main\cpp\world\src\world.c:1:
  ../../../../src/main/cpp/world/include\world.h:1:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
  #include <string>
           ^~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.`

Comment: So, some problems in your code itself. BTW, `<string>` is a header for **C++** program. But you use it in `.c` file which is intended to have **C** code.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. I'll disclose that in the actual project (this is nothing but rather a simulation) I use a C++ project which uses two C libraries (libmicrohttpd and other one). Is it possible to do such thing? The parent CMake to be for c++ and the child CMake to be for C

Comment: And now frankly I get an error that "hello.h" could not be found

Comment: C++/C compatibility are mostly for **headers**, not for the implementation. For every header you should decide, whether it is allowed to include it from C and whether it is allowed to include it from C++. You may have a header for both languages, it just needed to be properly written.

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? I have the exact same problem..